# What exactly does this syntax do? (in relation to c-style structs)

Tags: c

I understand the whole typedef-ing a struct in C concept so that you can avoid using the keyword struct whenever you use it.  I'm still a little confused about what's going on here though.

Can someone tell me the various things this structure definition is doing?

```
typedef struct work_tag {
    //contents.
} work_t, *work_p;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It defines two typedefs, like:

```
typedef struct work_tag {
    //contents.
} work_t;

typedef struct work_tag *work_p;
```

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers say, it defines two typedefs, one named `work_t` that refers to `struct work_tag`, and another name `work_p` that refers to `struct work_tag*`.

Note that a `typedef` does not create a new type.  All it does is create an *alias* for an existing type.  `struct work_tag` and `work_t` are not two similar types, they're two names for *exactly* the same type.

Now let's discuss why you'd want to do this.

The types `struct work_tag` and `struct work_tag*` already have perfectly good names.  A `typedef` gives you a way to refer to those types using a single identifier, but in my opinion that's really not much of an advantage.  And a `typedef` for a pointer type can actually be a bit dangerous.  If you want to define a name for a truly opaque type, where code that uses it doesn't take advantage of the fact that it's a struct or a pointer, a `typedef` is a good solution; otherwise, you're just obscuuring important information.

I'd just write:

```
struct work {
    // contents
};
```

and then refer to the type as `struct work`, and to a pointer to the type as `struct work*`.

But if you really feel the need to have a one-word name for the type, there's no need to use different names for the tag and the typedef:

```
typedef struct work {
    // contents
} work;
```

Now you can refer to the type either as `struct work` or as `work`, and to the pointer type either as `struct work*` or as `work*`.  (C++ does this implicitly; C does not.)  Note that if a `struct work` contains a pointer to another `struct work`, you can't use the typedef name inside the definition; the typedef name doesn't become visible until the end of definition.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a `typedef` like a variable declaration.  Just like you can do `int a, b` to make two `int` variables, you can do `typedef int a_t, b_t` to make two types in a single `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

It's assigning two alternative names to existing types:

```
work_t -> struct work_tag
work_p -> struct work_tag *
```

Comment: It doesn't define new types; it defines new names for existing types.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right. I've updated my answer to avoid any confusion. Thanks for your feedback.